# XCode blue folders aren't being treated as subdirectories?

Tags: xcode, filesystems

Okay, I had asked a question earlier about how I could create my own directories within XCode so as to be able to search for specific files more efficiently.  I re-imported my files, this time making sure to create folder references instead of flat groups.  Everything looks good, and my files are neatly organized in blue folders.

Now I had *thought* this would mean the paths to the files within these folders would change, and I could search through the new, more specific paths (instead of having to search through the contents of the entire application bundle every time).  But the path for *every file* in *any folder* is still identical to what it was earlier.

For example:  a text file called "items.txt" is located within the "SupportingFiles" folder that I imported as a reference.  I would expect the path to include "/SupportingFiles/items.txt".  But the path is logged as **/Users/Mike/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/(lots of numbers and text)/Adventurer BASE.app/items.txt**.

Or "xxDefault.txt", which is included in the "Defaults" folder, which itself is in the "SupportingFiles" folder.  I would expect to see "SupportingFiles/Defaults/xxDefault.txt" or something like it.  But again, the logged path ends in "**Adventurer BASE.app/xxDefault.txt**"

Every single file in any location has a path ending in "**Adventurer BASE.app/(file name)**".  Doesn't matter if it's on the simulator or an actual device.  I thought importing the resources within folder references (blue folders) was supposed to do the trick, but evidently there's something else to be done.

Clearly I am misundertanding XCode's filing system.  Any help figuring it out would be awesome, as I'm about to rip my hair out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a caching issue, my first idea would be to delete the build directory by holding down the **alt** key, access the **Product** menu and select **Clean Build Folder...** in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it.  I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

After checking @InsertWittyName's suggestion (which is fairly likely correct), make sure that in your Copy Files step you're copying the folder reference and not the individual files.

Answer (score 1):

The blue folder in Xcode is within the main bundle.  It is not in the "Application Support" (NSApplicationSupportDirectory) tree.  The path to the blue Xcode folder is:

```
NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SupportingFiles"];
```

Comment: The Application Support directory is where the iPhone Simulator is - it doesn't appear the poster is referencing it directly.